# Ignore case in grep alias

Tags: alias, csh

I'm having an alias to look for lines that set value of variables in Tcl like this:

```
alias vgrep 'grep -rn "set\s\+\!:1\s\+"'
```

Let's say I have a test.tcl file like:

```
set result 0
set RESULT 1
...
```

When I use `vgrep result test.tcl -i` *(--ignore-case)*, it just prints the first line of the file, which I supposed it to print both lines.

But when use `grep -rn "set\s\+result\s\+" test.tcl -i`, it prints both lines.

So, what's the problem here. Any idea would help. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but there's a way to debug this. If you replace `grep` with `echo grep` in all places, it will only print the according call after (!) the different shell substitutions, showing you the exact invocations.

Comment: The `grep` I know how to use will accept the `-i` option to **ignore** case. Good luck.